# Delete a row from sqlite database inside a recyclerview

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a notepad app that stores the notes in sqlite database and displays them in recyclerview. I have a drawable in my recycler view and I want to delete database row by clicking on it. with the code I wrote, when I click on the image the recycleview item disappears but when I open the app again the note is still there. I dont know how to delete it. here's my code :

```
public class ModelRs {
private String title;
private String content;
int id ;

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
```

here's my Databasehelper class and the insert and delete methods

```
public void insert(ModelRs modelRs) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(c_title, modelRs.getTitle());
    values.put(c_content, modelRs.getContent());
    values.put(c_id,modelRs.getId());

    try {
        this.getWritableDatabase().insert(t_name, null, values);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public List<ModelRs> list() {
    List<ModelRs> list = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor c = this.getWritableDatabase().query(t_name, new String[]{c_id, c_title, c_content}, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            ModelRs modelRs = new ModelRs();
            modelRs.setTitle(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(c_title)));
            modelRs.setContent(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(c_content)));

            list.add(modelRs);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    return list;
}



public void delete(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    sqLiteDatabase.delete(t_name, c_id + "=" + id, null) ;
}
}
```

here's my recyclerview adapter. the image on click listener method is in the view holder class

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AdapterRs.ViewHolderMain holder, final int position) {
    final ModelRs model = modelRs.get(position);
    holder.TextView_title.setText(model.getTitle());
    holder.TextView_content.setText(model.getContent());

}


class ViewHolderMain extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView TextView_title;
    private TextView TextView_content;
    private ImageView ImageDelete ;
    int id;
    public ViewHolderMain(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        TextView_title=itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextView_title);
        TextView_content=itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextView_content);
        ImageDelete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteicon) ;
        itemView.setClickable(true);
        ImageDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                id = getAdapterPosition() ;
                mydatabase = new DataBaseHelper(context) ;
                mydatabase.delete(id);
                modelRs.remove(id) ;
                notifyItemRemoved(id);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'm new to SQLite database. Please help me if you can

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for how to create sufficient example code, instead of posting it altogether... while the `Adapter` might be rather suitable to interact with the database, than the `ViewHolder` (single responsibility principle). `id = getAdapterPosition();` is wrong; this returns the index and not the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write onClick event on viewholder class. In your case "ViewHolderMain". you have to put

```
itemView.setClickable(true);
```

on ViewHolderMain constructor. then you can simply write the on click event.

```
ImageDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Your delete method 
            }
        });
```

After deleting item from sqlite u must add

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to delete the item from view as well ..

Comment: How should I write my delete method?

Comment: inside onclick method,

mydatabase = new DataBaseHelper(context);
mydatabase.delete(modelRs.get(getAdaptePosition).getId());

Comment: Thanks. I've forgotten to setId in my insert method. I did that and then followed your answer. problem solved. /// mydatabase.delete(id);
                    modelRs.remove(getAdapterPosition()) ;
                    notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition()); ///